# using XSLT to display image series with captions in XHTML

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to display a series of images each with its own caption using XSLT. I've coded the images and the captions by nesting `<img>` and then `<figcaption>` within  but the resultant html does not display as intended (the captions are not lining up with corresponding images). Is there a way to nest `<xsl: for-each>` for the captions within the images? Here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">    
    <xsl:output method="html"/>      
    <xsl:template match="letter">       
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    #wrapper {min-height: 100%;}                    
                    #figcaption {
                    text-align: left;
                    }
                    #main {
                    padding-top: 15px;;
                    width: 1200px;
                    }                    
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="wrapper">                    
                    <div id="images">
                        <figure>                                
                            <xsl:if test="image">                                    
                                <xsl:for-each select="image/@xlink:href">                                        
                                    <img>                                            
                                        <xsl:attribute name="src">                                                
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>                                                
                                        </xsl:attribute>                                            
                                    </img>                                        
                                </xsl:for-each>                                    
                            </xsl:if>                                
                            <xsl:if test="image/@label">                                    
                                <xsl:for-each select="image/@label">                                        
                                    <figcaption><xsl:value-of select="."/></figcaption>                                        
                                </xsl:for-each>                                    
                            </xsl:if>                                
                        </figure>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the corresponding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLT.xsl"?>
<letter xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    
    <image label="page 1" xlink:href="http://tinyurl.com/nu7zmhc"/> 
    <image label="page 2" xlink:href="http://tinyurl.com/pysyztr"/> 
    <title>Letter from Shawn Schuyler</title>   
    <date>1963-06-30</date>     
    <language>English</language>    
    <creator>       
        <firstName>William</firstName>      
        <lastName>Schultz</lastName>
        <street>Unites States Disciplinary Barracks</street>            
        <city>Fort Leavenworth</city>           
        <state abbr="KS">Kansas</state>     
    </creator>      
</letter>
```

My desired output in html is basically this for each image:

```
<figure>
    <img src='image.jpg'/>
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Can you post your source XML and desired output?  Also, as a general rule avoid `foreach` in XSL; use template matching; it'll be faster and cleaner.

Comment: Added XML and desired output. How would you make this work with template matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="letter">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          #wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
          #figcaption {
          text-align: left;
          }
          #main {
          padding-top: 15px;;
          width: 1200px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="images">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./image"></xsl:apply-templates>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="letter/image">
    <xsl:element name="figure">
      <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="./@xlink:href"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./@label"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="letter/image/@label">
    <xsl:element name="figcaption">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`xsl:apply-templates` says where anything matching the pattern specified in `select` should be put (with the dot showing the current element's context).

`xsl:template` is matched against the source document based on the path given in `match`.  Any hits are processed in parallel, then later stitched together based on where the `apply-templates` elements indicate.

NB: depending on your XSLT engine having `output="html"` may have different effects on your `img` element.  In HTML5 the `img` element is defined as not requiring a close tag (or being self-closing), so the engine won't close that tag.  Arguments about whether that inconsistency is a good choice or not can be found throughout the net.

Ref: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

A good article on this alternate approach to `for-each` can be found here: http://gregbee.ch/blog/using-xsl-for-each-is-almost-always-wrong
You'll find with XLST that once the concept of a template clicks your code will become way shorter are simpler to maintain.

Comment: Wow! Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I'm just getting started with XSLT but this is already making a lot more sense than `for-each`. Articles are now bookmarked! Thanks again for your help and the extra resources.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
exclude-result-prefixes="xlink">

<xsl:template match="/letter">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
            #wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
            #figcaption {
            text-align: left;
            }
            #main {
            padding-top: 15px;;
            width: 1200px;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="images">
                    <xsl:for-each select="image">
                        <figure>
                            <img src='{@xlink:href}'/>
                            <figcaption>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>  
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:**

1. There's nothing wrong with using `xsl:for-each`, especially in a
   simple case like this;
2. There *is* something wrong with using `xsl:element` when you can use a *literal result element*. And while XSLT is naturally verbose, using the *attribute value template* can reduce the code (quite significanltly, as you can see in this case).